# Reduced performance in mysql after upgrade to 5.6.27

Tags: mysql, performance

Our application was using MySql version 4.0.24 for a long time. We are trying to migrate it to version 5.6.27. 
But, on testing the performance on 5.6.27, even the simple selects and updates are 30-40% slower when we are doing load testing. The CPU and IO speeds are much better than the older server. The storage engine of the tables is MyIsam in both versions. There's only one connection to the database. We tried the following options:

1. Changing storage engine to InnoDb - this reduce the performance drastically (70% slower)
2. Changing the innodb log size and buffer size - didn't help much
3. Increasing key buffer size with MyIsam storage engine for tables. - It made no difference

We tried modifying other parameters like query cache, tmp_table_size, heap_table_size. But, none of them made any difference.

Can you please let me know if there's any other option that we can try?

Here's a copy of my.cnf:

```
lower-case-table-names=1
myisam-recover=FORCE
key_buffer_size=2000M
```

Comment: You will probably get better answers from ServerFault ...

Comment: Please show us a copy of my.cnf. In a Linux server, it can typically be found at /etc/my.cnf

Comment: is this all my.cnf ? usually same server with same my.cnf and different versions of mysql behave the same way

Comment: "Simple selects and updates" -- are you timing them individually?  Or as a batch of queries?

Comment: InnoDB is probably slower only because of not adequately tuning the variables.  Try again with innodb_buffer_pool_size at 70% of available ram and innodb_flush_log_at_trx_comment set to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple options, here are the configurations that worked for us. There may be other solutions as well but this worked for us.

**Option 1:**

1. Turned off the performance schema
2. Added a  couple of jdbc connection parameters: useConfigs=maxPerformance&maintainTimeStats=false

**Option 2:**

Migrate to MariaDB. From a performance perspective, this worked out really well. It was giving a 5%  better performance compared to mysql for our system. But, we couldn't pursue this option due to non-technical reasons.

Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can look at are whether the two servers have the same amount of RAM or not as it may be that the old server has more RAM and so can cache more things in memory.

You can also look at how are you connecting to the MySQL server - is it over a network?  Is that network speed / quality different?  Is one server accessed locally and the other over a network.

You tried tuning some good parameters, but in case there are ones you're missing, you can run `mysql -e 'show variables'` on both servers and then use a tool like Winmerge to compare the values of the two and see what might be different that you might not have thought of.

Comment: 5.6 has soooo many more `VARIABLES` that the Winmerge will be hard to read.

Comment: Given what the OP has already tried, I feel like it may be worth it at this point.